# How to refresh the list of items in the combobox delegate which represents the data of a QSqlRelationalTablemodel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtsql

I've recently examined an example from Chapter 15 of “Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt” by Mark Summerfield which presents the use of SQL Database TableView modelling. In this original example, I found a little dysfunctionality which prevents the table views from refreshing combobox delegates (being QSqlRelation). Simply, the combobox delegates in the table view which represent the data of QSqlRelationalTableModel, are not updated once relational tables have been modified.

The original file name is chap15/assetmanager.pyw and can be find [elsewhere](https://github.com/ghosert/VimProject/blob/master/pyqt/book_samples/chap15/assetmanager.pyw). Below I provide a code snippet necessary to reproduce the problem.

In this example, a relation with QSqlTableModel (self.assetModel and self.logModel) is established for actions and categories (QSqlRelationalTableModel) which can be modified using the combobox delegates (LogDelegate or AssetDelegate). New actions or categories can be added through the ReferenceDataDlg dialog.

New record added in Categories

[image]

However, once the dialog ReferenceDataDlg is closed the newly created record does not appear in the combobox delegate even though the new records exist in the SQL table for actions or categories.

Combobox delegate not refreshed

[image]

How can I programmatically refresh the list of items in the combobox delegate in the table views: self.assetView and self.logView?

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from future_builtins import *

import os
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import (PYQT_VERSION_STR, QDate, QFile, QRegExp,
        QString, QVariant, Qt, SIGNAL)
from PyQt4.QtGui import (QApplication, QCursor, QDateEdit, QDialog,
        QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QPixmap,
        QPushButton, QRegExpValidator, QStyleOptionViewItem, QTableView,
        QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt4.QtSql import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlRelation,
        QSqlRelationalDelegate, QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlTableModel)

MAC = True
try:
    from PyQt4.QtGui import qt_mac_set_native_menubar
except ImportError:
    MAC = False

ID = 0
NAME = ASSETID = 1
CATEGORYID = DATE = DESCRIPTION = 2
ROOM = ACTIONID = 3

ACQUIRED = 1

def createFakeData():
    import random

    print("Dropping tables...")
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE assets")
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE logs")
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE actions")
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE categories")
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Creating tables...")
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE actions (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)""")
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE categories (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL)""")
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE assets (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                categoryid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                room VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY (categoryid) REFERENCES categories)""")
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE logs (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                assetid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                date DATE NOT NULL,
                actionid INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY (assetid) REFERENCES assets,
                FOREIGN KEY (actionid) REFERENCES actions)""")
    QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Populating tables...")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO actions (name, description) "
                "VALUES ('Acquired', 'When installed')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO actions (name, description) "
                "VALUES ('Broken', 'When failed and unusable')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO actions (name, description) "
                "VALUES ('Repaired', 'When back in service')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO actions (name, description) "
                "VALUES ('Routine maintenance', "
                "'When tested, refilled, etc.')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO categories (name, description) VALUES "
                "('Computer Equipment', "
                "'Monitors, System Units, Peripherals, etc.')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO categories (name, description) VALUES "
                "('Furniture', 'Chairs, Tables, Desks, etc.')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO categories (name, description) VALUES "
                "('Electrical Equipment', 'Non-computer electricals')")
    today = QDate.currentDate()
    floors = range(1, 12) + range(14, 28)
    monitors = (('17" LCD Monitor', 1),
                ('20" LCD Monitor', 1),
                ('21" LCD Monitor', 1),
                ('21" CRT Monitor', 1),
                ('24" CRT Monitor', 1))
    computers = (("Computer (32-bit/80GB/0.5GB)", 1),
                 ("Computer (32-bit/100GB/1GB)", 1),
                 ("Computer (32-bit/120GB/1GB)", 1),
                 ("Computer (64-bit/240GB/2GB)", 1),
                 ("Computer (64-bit/320GB/4GB)", 1))
    printers = (("Laser Printer (4 ppm)", 1),
                ("Laser Printer (6 ppm)", 1),
                ("Laser Printer (8 ppm)", 1),
                ("Laser Printer (16 ppm)", 1))
    chairs = (("Secretary Chair", 2),
              ("Executive Chair (Basic)", 2),
              ("Executive Chair (Ergonimic)", 2),
              ("Executive Chair (Hi-Tech)", 2))
    desks = (("Desk (Basic, 3 drawer)", 2),
             ("Desk (Standard, 3 drawer)", 2),
             ("Desk (Executive, 3 drawer)", 2),
             ("Desk (Executive, 4 drawer)", 2),
             ("Desk (Large, 4 drawer)", 2))
    furniture = (("Filing Cabinet (3 drawer)", 2),
                 ("Filing Cabinet (4 drawer)", 2),
                 ("Filing Cabinet (5 drawer)", 2),
                 ("Bookcase (4 shelves)", 2),
                 ("Bookcase (6 shelves)", 2),
                 ("Table (4 seater)", 2),
                 ("Table (8 seater)", 2),
                 ("Table (12 seater)", 2))
    electrical = (("Fan (3 speed)", 3),
                  ("Fan (5 speed)", 3),
                  ("Photocopier (4 ppm)", 3),
                  ("Photocopier (6 ppm)", 3),
                  ("Photocopier (8 ppm)", 3),
                  ("Shredder", 3))
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO assets (name, categoryid, room) "
                  "VALUES (:name, :categoryid, :room)")
    logQuery = QSqlQuery()
    logQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO logs (assetid, date, actionid) "
                     "VALUES (:assetid, :date, :actionid)")
    assetid = 1
    for i in range(20):
        room = QVariant("{0:02d}{1:02d}".format(
                random.choice(floors), random.randint(1, 62)))
        for name, category in (random.choice(monitors),
                random.choice(computers), random.choice(chairs),
                random.choice(desks), random.choice(furniture)):
            query.bindValue(":name", QVariant(name))
            query.bindValue(":categoryid", QVariant(category))
            query.bindValue(":room", room)
            query.exec_()
            logQuery.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid))
            when = today.addDays(-random.randint(7, 1500))
            logQuery.bindValue(":date", QVariant(when))
            logQuery.bindValue(":actionid", QVariant(ACQUIRED))
            logQuery.exec_()
            if random.random() > 0.7:
                logQuery.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid))
                when = when.addDays(random.randint(1, 1500))
                if when <= today:
                    logQuery.bindValue(":date", QVariant(when))
                    logQuery.bindValue(":actionid",
                            QVariant(random.choice((2, 4))))
                    logQuery.exec_()
            assetid += 1
        if random.random() > 0.8:
            name, category = random.choice(printers)
            query.bindValue(":name", QVariant(name))
            query.bindValue(":categoryid", QVariant(category))
            query.bindValue(":room", room)
            query.exec_()
            logQuery.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid))
            when = today.addDays(-random.randint(7, 1500))
            logQuery.bindValue(":date", QVariant(when))
            logQuery.bindValue(":actionid", QVariant(ACQUIRED))
            logQuery.exec_()
            if random.random() > 0.6:
                logQuery.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid))
                when = when.addDays(random.randint(1, 1500))
                if when <= today:
                    logQuery.bindValue(":date", QVariant(when))
                    logQuery.bindValue(":actionid",
                            QVariant(random.choice((2, 4))))
                    logQuery.exec_()
            assetid += 1
        if random.random() > 0.6:
            name, category = random.choice(electrical)
            query.bindValue(":name", QVariant(name))
            query.bindValue(":categoryid", QVariant(category))
            query.bindValue(":room", room)
            query.exec_()
            logQuery.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid))
            when = today.addDays(-random.randint(7, 1500))
            logQuery.bindValue(":date", QVariant(when))
            logQuery.bindValue(":actionid", QVariant(ACQUIRED))
            logQuery.exec_()
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                logQuery.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid))
                when = when.addDays(random.randint(1, 1500))
                if when <= today:
                    logQuery.bindValue(":date", QVariant(when))
                    logQuery.bindValue(":actionid",
                            QVariant(random.choice((2, 4))))
                    logQuery.exec_()
            assetid += 1
        QApplication.processEvents()

    print("Assets:")
    query.exec_("SELECT id, name, categoryid, room FROM assets "
                "ORDER by id")
    categoryQuery = QSqlQuery()
    while query.next():
        id = query.value(0).toInt()[0]
        name = unicode(query.value(1).toString())
        categoryid = query.value(2).toInt()[0]
        room = unicode(query.value(3).toString())
        categoryQuery.exec_(QString("SELECT name FROM categories "
                "WHERE id = %1").arg(categoryid))
        category = "{0}".format(categoryid)
        if categoryQuery.next():
            category = unicode(categoryQuery.value(0).toString())
        print("{0}: {1} [{2}] {3}".format(id, name, category, room))
    QApplication.processEvents()


class ReferenceDataDlg(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, table, title, parent=None):
        super(ReferenceDataDlg, self).__init__(parent)

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable(table)
        self.model.setSort(NAME, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model.setHeaderData(ID, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("ID"))
        self.model.setHeaderData(NAME, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("Name"))
        self.model.setHeaderData(DESCRIPTION, Qt.Horizontal,
                                 QVariant("Description"))
        self.model.select()

        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.view.setColumnHidden(ID, True)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

        addButton = QPushButton("&Add")
        deleteButton = QPushButton("&Delete")
        okButton = QPushButton("&OK")
        if not MAC:
            addButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
            deleteButton.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(addButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(deleteButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(okButton)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(addButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.addRecord)
        self.connect(okButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.accept)

        self.setWindowTitle(
                "Asset Manager - Edit {0} Reference Data".format(title))


    def addRecord(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        index = self.model.index(row, NAME)
        self.view.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.view.edit(index)


class AssetDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AssetDelegate, self).__init__(parent)


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        myoption = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        if index.column() == ROOM:
            myoption.displayAlignment |= (Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        QSqlRelationalDelegate.paint(self, painter, myoption, index)


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == ROOM:
            editor = QLineEdit(parent)
            regex = QRegExp(r"(?:0[1-9]|1[0124-9]|2[0-7])"
                                   r"(?:0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[012])")
            validator = QRegExpValidator(regex, parent)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
            editor.setInputMask("9999")
            editor.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter)
            return editor
        else:
            return QSqlRelationalDelegate.createEditor(self, parent,
                                                       option, index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.column() == ROOM:
            text = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toString()
            editor.setText(text)
        else:
            QSqlRelationalDelegate.setEditorData(self, editor, index)


    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == ROOM:
            model.setData(index, QVariant(editor.text()))
        else:
            QSqlRelationalDelegate.setModelData(self, editor, model,
                                                index)


class LogDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LogDelegate, self).__init__(parent)


    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        myoption = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        if index.column() == DATE:
            myoption.displayAlignment |= (Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignVCenter)
        QSqlRelationalDelegate.paint(self, painter, myoption, index)


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if (index.column() == ACTIONID and
            index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toInt()[0] ==
            ACQUIRED): # Acquired is read-only
            return
        if index.column() == DATE:
            editor = QDateEdit(parent)
            editor.setMaximumDate(QDate.currentDate())
            editor.setDisplayFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            if PYQT_VERSION_STR >= "4.1.0":
                editor.setCalendarPopup(True)
            editor.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|
                                Qt.AlignVCenter)
            return editor
        else:
            return QSqlRelationalDelegate.createEditor(self, parent,
                                                       option, index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.column() == DATE:
            date = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole).toDate()
            editor.setDate(date)
        else:
            QSqlRelationalDelegate.setEditorData(self, editor, index)


    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == DATE:
            model.setData(index, QVariant(editor.date()))
        else:
            QSqlRelationalDelegate.setModelData(self, editor, model,
                                                index)


class MainForm(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__()

        self.assetModel = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
        self.assetModel.setTable("assets")
        self.assetModel.setRelation(CATEGORYID,
                QSqlRelation("categories", "id", "name"))
        self.assetModel.setSort(ROOM, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.assetModel.setHeaderData(ID, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("ID"))
        self.assetModel.setHeaderData(NAME, Qt.Horizontal,
                QVariant("Name"))
        self.assetModel.setHeaderData(CATEGORYID, Qt.Horizontal,
                QVariant("Category"))
        self.assetModel.setHeaderData(ROOM, Qt.Horizontal,
                QVariant("Room"))
        self.assetModel.select()

        self.assetView = QTableView()
        self.assetView.setModel(self.assetModel)
        self.assetView.setItemDelegate(AssetDelegate(self))
        self.assetView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.assetView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.assetView.setColumnHidden(ID, True)
        self.assetView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        assetLabel = QLabel("A&ssets")
        assetLabel.setBuddy(self.assetView)

        self.logModel = QSqlRelationalTableModel(self)
        self.logModel.setTable("logs")
        self.logModel.setRelation(ACTIONID,
                QSqlRelation("actions", "id", "name"))
        self.logModel.setSort(DATE, Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.logModel.setHeaderData(DATE, Qt.Horizontal, QVariant("Date"))
        self.logModel.setHeaderData(ACTIONID, Qt.Horizontal,
                QVariant("Action"))
        self.logModel.select()

        self.logView = QTableView()
        self.logView.setModel(self.logModel)
        self.logView.setItemDelegate(LogDelegate(self))
        self.logView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.SingleSelection)
        self.logView.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.logView.setColumnHidden(ID, True)
        self.logView.setColumnHidden(ASSETID, True)
        self.logView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.logView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        logLabel = QLabel("&Logs")
        logLabel.setBuddy(self.logView)

        editActionsButton = QPushButton("&Edit Actions...")
        editCategoriesButton = QPushButton("Ed&it Categories...")
        quitButton = QPushButton("&Quit")
        for button in (editActionsButton, editCategoriesButton, quitButton):
            if MAC:
                button.setDefault(False)
                button.setAutoDefault(False)
            else:
                button.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        dataLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        dataLayout.addWidget(assetLabel)
        dataLayout.addWidget(self.assetView, 1)
        dataLayout.addWidget(logLabel)
        dataLayout.addWidget(self.logView)
        buttonLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(editActionsButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(editCategoriesButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(quitButton)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(dataLayout, 1)
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(self.assetView.selectionModel(),
                SIGNAL(("currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)")),
                self.assetChanged)
        self.connect(editActionsButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                     self.editActions)
        self.connect(editCategoriesButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                     self.editCategories)
        self.connect(quitButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.done)

        self.assetChanged(self.assetView.currentIndex())
        self.setMinimumWidth(650)
        self.setWindowTitle("Asset Manager")


    def done(self, result=1):
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_("DELETE FROM logs WHERE logs.assetid NOT IN"
                    "(SELECT id FROM assets)")
        QDialog.done(self, 1)


    def assetChanged(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            record = self.assetModel.record(index.row())
            id = record.value("id").toInt()[0]
            self.logModel.setFilter(QString("assetid = %1").arg(id))
        else:
            self.logModel.setFilter("assetid = -1")
        self.logModel.reset() # workaround for Qt <= 4.3.3/SQLite bug
        self.logModel.select()
        self.logView.horizontalHeader().setVisible(
                self.logModel.rowCount() > 0)
        if PYQT_VERSION_STR < "4.1.0":
            self.logView.setColumnHidden(ID, True)
            self.logView.setColumnHidden(ASSETID, True)


    def addAsset(self):
        row = (self.assetView.currentIndex().row()
               if self.assetView.currentIndex().isValid() else 0)

        QSqlDatabase.database().transaction()
        self.assetModel.insertRow(row)
        index = self.assetModel.index(row, NAME)
        self.assetView.setCurrentIndex(index)

        assetid = 1
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_("SELECT MAX(id) FROM assets")
        if query.next():
            assetid = query.value(0).toInt()[0]
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO logs (assetid, date, actionid) "
                      "VALUES (:assetid, :date, :actionid)")
        query.bindValue(":assetid", QVariant(assetid + 1))
        query.bindValue(":date", QVariant(QDate.currentDate()))
        query.bindValue(":actionid", QVariant(ACQUIRED))
        query.exec_()
        QSqlDatabase.database().commit()
        self.assetView.edit(index)


    def addAction(self):
        index = self.assetView.currentIndex()
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        QSqlDatabase.database().transaction()
        record = self.assetModel.record(index.row())
        assetid = record.value(ID).toInt()[0]

        row = self.logModel.rowCount()
        self.logModel.insertRow(row)
        self.logModel.setData(self.logModel.index(row, ASSETID),
                              QVariant(assetid))
        self.logModel.setData(self.logModel.index(row, DATE),
                              QVariant(QDate.currentDate()))
        QSqlDatabase.database().commit()
        index = self.logModel.index(row, ACTIONID)
        self.logView.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.logView.edit(index)


    def editActions(self):
        form = ReferenceDataDlg("actions", "Action", self)
        form.exec_()


    def editCategories(self):
        form = ReferenceDataDlg("categories", "Category", self)
        form.exec_()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "assetsdb.db")
    create = not QFile.exists(filename)
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(filename)
    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Asset Manager",
            QString("Database Error: %1")
            .arg(db.lastError().text()))
        sys.exit(1)

    if create:
        createFakeData()

    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    if create:
        app.processEvents()
        app.restoreOverrideCursor()
    app.exec_()
    del form
    del db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that for reasons of efficiency the model associated to the `QComboBox` of `QSqlRelationalDelegate` is not reloaded every time the `QComboBox` is shown, the solution is to reload that model using the `select()` method:

```
class AssetDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate):
    # ...
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == ROOM:
            editor = QLineEdit(parent)
            regex = QRegExp(
                r"(?:0[1-9]|1[0124-9]|2[0-7])" r"(?:0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|6[012])"
            )
            validator = QRegExpValidator(regex, parent)
            editor.setValidator(validator)
            editor.setInputMask("9999")
            editor.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter)
            return editor
        else:
            editor = QSqlRelationalDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)
            if isinstance(editor, QComboBox) and instance(
                editor.model(), QSqlTableModel
            ):
                editor.model().select()
            return editor
```

Comment: many thanks. it seems that  editor = QSqlRelationalDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index) and  editor.model().select() are sufficient.